# Non payment on (Phone) Handset Lease

Tags: small-claims-court, civil-procedure, new-jersey

I am in a situation where my friend was not able to get a phone contract under his name, and I being a good friend agreed to add a line to my account and leased a phone for him (all under my account).

Recently we had a few misunderstandings and the person decided to stop making lease payments on the device. I reached out to the person and advised him that I (we) do not own the phone, so he must either return the phone to me so I can bring it back to the Carrier or start making the lease payments, and he ignored my requests.

Due to the above, I am interested in bringing this person to court. Now, my question: Is that even possible?  What's the term used for this legal situation? What paper work would I file with the courts to get this moving?

**State: New Jersey**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The term for this situation is a "civil dispute."  It can be resolved via a civil claim.  In New Jersey, for claims under $3000, you can use the Small Claims courts.  The process is designed to be followed without the assistance of counsel.  [Let the internet be your guide](https://www.google.com/#q=new+jersey+small+claims+court).

Comment: Awesomely awesome!!! thank you very much, this answers my questions.

Comment: FYI lmgtfy usage is generally frowned upon, at least over on StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - You mean because we prefer the answer to contain all useful information, rather than to reference it?  Or something else?

Comment: @feetwet That, and also new users tend to not like it.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Oh yeah, I forgot how patronizing that link can be.  Not appropriate here; I just replaced with conventional Google link.